# Raspberry Pi 3 SD card not 'clickling'

Tags: pi-3

I have just upgraded from a Pi2 to a Pi3 but when I normally put in a SD card it clicks into place and continues to boot up once powered.

My new Pi3, the SD card slides in, but there's no 'click'. Plus when I power nothing boots up.

Have I got a physical issue with my Pi3 SD card slot?

Comment: The SD card slot on the Pi 3 is different to the slots on the previous Pi's as the SD card just slots in. It is held in place by friction, it solves the issue with the previous SD card slots where if you grabbed the Pi in the wrong place while it was on; the SD card would be disconnected. Potentially causing it to be corrupted.

Answer (score 7):

The Pi 2 has a spring-click sd card slot, but on the Pi Zero and the Pi 3, this has been changed to a friction fit slot, because they are smaller and more durable. There is nothing wrong with your Pi 3 and it should work fine. [Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=140658).

Comment: Thanks - is there some trick to removing it?  I have to remove the board from the case now every time I want to swap SD cards now.

Comment: try to stick a tape on the back-top side of sdcard and pull it out